# If $P(X\in A)=0$ or $1$ then $X$ has a degenerate distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be a real random variable on a probability space. Suppose that $P(X\in A)=0$ or $1$ for all $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Is true that $X$ has a degenerate distribution? Is it also true if $X$ takes values in a more general space?

Regarding the real case I did the following:

Consider the partition $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n \in\mathbb Z} [n,n+1)$. By $\sigma$-additivity we have $\sum_{n \in\mathbb Z}P_X\big([n,n+1)\big)=1$. Therefore there exists some integer $n$ such that $X\in[n,n+1]$ almost surely. Using additivity again we get $P_X\big([n,n+1/2)\big)+P_X\big([n+1/2,n+1]\big)=1$, so either $X\in[n,n+1/2]$ almost surely or $X\in[n+1/2,n+1]$ almost surely . Continuing inductively, we obtain a decreasing sequence of closed intervals $I_k$, each  with length $|I_k|=1/k$ and $P_X(I_k)=1$. By the nested interval theorem we have

$$\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty I_k=\{x\}$$

for some $x\in\mathbb R$. Moreover, by the properties of measures, we have $P_X(\{x\})=\lim_{k\to\infty} P_X(I_k)=1$. Hence $X=x$ almost surely.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  It also works (by the same method) if $X$ is a "random element" of a Polish space.

Comment: Similar to your argument, I just think in a naive way that a random variable $X$ is non-degenerate if and only if there exist two disjoint set $A, B$ such that $P(X \in A) > 0$ and $P(X \in B) > 0$. May only work in some simple spaces / cases only though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is great. Here is another method. Let $x=\sup\{y\in \Bbb R:P(X\le y)=0\}$. Then $$P(X<x)=\lim_{y\nearrow x} P(X\le y)=\lim_{y\nearrow x}0=0.$$ but $$P(X\le x)=\lim_{y\searrow x}P(X\le y)=\lim_{y\searrow x}1=1.$$
Combined, these prove $P(X=x)=1$.

Comment: Thank you indeed this method is much more direct! Can you generalize it in $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: @Alphie 1D $\implies$ $n$D. If $\vec X=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$, and $P(\vec X\in A)\in \{0,1\}$ for all $A\subseteq \Bbb R^n$, then in particular $P(X_i\in B)\in\{0,1\}$ for all $B\subseteq \Bbb R$, so $\exists x_i:P(X_i=x_i)=1$ by 1D result, so $P(\vec X=(x_1,\dots,x_n))=1$.

Comment: Ah yes of course!